# How should i add Object in NSDictionary for the same key at runtime?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add value as array in NSDctionary for the same key, i don't how should i add like that, what i mean in PHP, we have add multi dimension array at runtime like fetching the value form DB like for the same key, we need to add into NSDictonary?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple objects associated with a single dictionary key, then you can store those objects in an *NSArray*, then add an *NSArray* instance for each key: